# Why can I use CMake supplied modules (CMakeDependentOption.cmake specifically) locally, but not on CI or Docker?

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, module, continuous-integration

I have a cmake project that successfully builds locally but errors with

```
  include could not find load file:

    CmakeDependentOption
```

when trying to build on a CI platform or in Docker. Note that CMakeDependentOption.cmake is a script that comes with cmake itself. So it should just be available. On CI to install cmake, I `wget` the relevant cmake release from their downloads page, unzip it and add the bin directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Then I use the `cmake` command to build my library. The result is the above error.

I suspect this means that a CMake variable (such as "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH" but not, since this variable seems to be empty at the start of the cmake script) is messed up or not set somehow. The path to the correct file to `include` is

```
<cmake_root>/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDependentOption.cmake
```

And I have verified that it exists manually. My question: is there a way to locate this directory from within cmake? Perhaps a `cmake --config` or `cmake --libs` mode (a bit like pkg-config?)

Failing that, does anybody have any suggestions as to why this is happening and how to get around it.

Comment: This looks like a typo on your side. `CmakeDependentOption` vs `CMakeDependentOption` is different on case sensitive files systems.

Comment: Yep, this was it. Thought something was fishy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally because most likely you don't use a linux based platform, like windows or mac. This is because linux filesystem are case sensitive. Which means `CmakeDependentOption` is different from `CMakeDependentOption`.

Docker runs containers in linux, so filenames are gonna be case sensitive, and the include is going to fail if the cases are different.